# Bootstrap CSS For 2 Column Image in a row not working

Tags: html, css, asp.net

**ASP.NET**

All images are showing one down to another (i.e.) in four rows.

But i expect to see two pictures in a row (2 columns per row).

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="Images/1st.jpg" width="50%" height="100%" alt="...">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="Images/1st.jpg" width="50%" height="100%" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="Images/1st.jpg" width="50%" height="100%" alt="...">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img src="Images/1st.jpg" width="50%" height="100%" alt="...">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Don't know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
 
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="HeightAdjustment" src="Images/1st.jpg" alt="..."><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="HeightAdjustment" src="Images/1st.jpg" alt="..."><br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="HeightAdjustment" src="Images/1st.jpg" alt="..."><br>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-6">
                <img class="HeightAdjustment" src="Images/1st.jpg" alt="..."><br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It might helps. Drag to left in jsfiddle you could see the two rows,,link is https://jsfiddle.net/9n3c8726/5/

Comment: Drag to left (To make full screen)